# How to mark @Test as failed in @AfterMethod

Tags: java, testng

I am trying to find out a way if there is any way in TetstNG to mark a test method annotated with `@Test` as failed inside `@AfterMethod`.

```
@Test
public void sampleTest() {
    // do some stuff
}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() {
    // 1st operation
    try {
        // some operation
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // mark sampleTest as failed
    }

    // 2nd operation
    try {
        // perform some cleanup here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // print something
    }
}
```

I have some verification to be done in all tests, which I am doing under 1st `try-catch` block in `tearDown()`. If there is an exception in that block, mark the test as failed. Then proceed for next `try-catch` block.

I cannot reverse the order of try-catch blocks in `tearDown()` because, 1st block depends on 2nd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge you cannot do it from within `@AfterMethod` configuration method, because the ITestResult object that gets passed to your configuration method [ Yes you can get access to the test method's result object by adding a parameter `ITestResult result` to your `@AfterMethod` annotated method ] is not used to update back the original test method's result.

But you can easily do this if you were to leverage the `IHookable` interface.
You can get more information on `IHookable` by referring to the official documentation [here](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#ihookable).

Here's an example that shows this in action.

```java
import org.testng.IHookCallBack;
import org.testng.IHookable;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClassSample implements IHookable {

  @Test
  public void testMethod1() {
    System.err.println("testMethod1");
  }

  @Test
  public void failMe() {
    System.err.println("failMe");
  }

  @Override
  public void run(IHookCallBack callBack, ITestResult result) {
    callBack.runTestMethod(result);
    if (result.getMethod().getMethodName().equalsIgnoreCase("failme")) {
      result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
      result.setThrowable(new RuntimeException("Simulating a failure"));
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** I am using TestNG `7.0.0-beta7` (latest released version as of today)